# How to prompt user regarding new app release in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

How can we configure react-native to notify user about the new app release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration or automatic thing, but there are several ways that you can achieve this matter. one is using some sort of file in some server and put the version number in it like:

```
{
  version: "2.4"
}
```

and the address would be like https://example.com/version.json

and everytime the user open the application ( or whenever you like ) you check that file and compare it to the local version. if the server version is newer then you ask the user to update the application.

another way is use Push notification services like FCM. whenever the app have update you send all users the notification about the new update.

the second way advantage is you can inform users about the update even they don't open the app, altough they have to install the app in order the receive the notification.

the next approach is just publish your app in play store. whenever you publish the new update the play store will inform user about the new update and user can easily update their app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [react-native-push-notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) library could be a solution. You can create some kind of trigger on the server when a new version is being deployed to launch a message kind of "New release of *MyApp* available!"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a json file on the server and initialise a paramter.

```
{
  "update":"false"
}
```

then check it when the app is launched. If the parameter you set in json file is true.

```
{
  "update":"true"
}
```

Then trigger a modal or popup for the update.

Comment: a version number would be better. Otherwise, if you set the config file to true, every user will receive that value; even if they have already updated.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the `react-native-check-version` package for this and it works well. https://github.com/includable/react-native-check-version